# MySQL drop unique key: needed in a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I`ve a table which look like this

```
CREATE TABLE `ratings` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `profile_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `stars` enum('1','2','3','4','5') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `survey_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ratings_profile_id_email_unique` (`profile_id`,`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ratings_token_unique` (`token`),
  KEY `survey_id` (`survey_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ratings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`survey_id`) REFERENCES `surveys` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `ratings_profile_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`profile_id`) REFERENCES `profiles` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

My goal is to delete the `ratings_profile_id_email_unique` key. I tried this statement

```
alter table ratings drop key ratings_profile_id_email_unique;
```

This produces: `Cannot drop index 'ratings_profile_id_email_unique': needed in a foreign key constraint`

What is wrong? How can a unique key needed in a fk constraint?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, in general, a foreign key constraint can refer to either a primary key or a unique key.  MySQL extends this to *any* indexed column(s), but that is not relevant here.

Somewhere in your data model, you have a foreign key reference using these two keys instead of `id`.  You need to fix such references in order to delete the index.

If you don't know where this is, you can use the `information_schema` tables, such as [`information_schema.referential_constraints`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/referential-constraints-table.html) and [`information_schema.key_column_usage`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html).

For instance, this gets foreign key constraints that reference `t`:

```
select *
from information_schema.referential_constraints rc
where rc.referenced_table_name = 't'
```

(You may want to include the schema in them.)  This is probably enough information, but if you need more `key_column_usage` can be more specific on the keys being used.

Comment: So you mean something like `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE K WHERE k.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'ratings_profile_id_email_unique';` and `select * from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS k WHERE k.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'ratings_profile_id_email_unique';`. The first one returns the tow fields (email, id) which the unique points and the second query an empty result set.  So the key is used only for the tow fields. Right?